# How do you insert with a reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, stl

I want to insert something into a STL list in C++, but I only have a reverse iterator. What is the usual way to accomplish this?

This works: (of course it does)

```
std::list<int> l;
std::list<int>::iterator forward = l.begin();
l.insert(forward, 5);
```

This doesn't work: (what should I do instead?)

```
std::list<int> l;
std::list<int>::reverse_iterator reverse = l.rbegin();
l.insert(reverse, 10);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`l.insert(reverse.base(), 10);` will insert '10' at the end, given your definition of the 'reverse' iterator. Actually, `l.rbegin().base() == l.end()`.

Answer (score 17):

Essentially, you don't.  See 19.2.5 in TCPPPL.

The `reverse_iterator` has a member called `base()` which will return a "regular" iterator.  So the following code would work in your example:

```
l.insert(reverse.base(), 10);
```

Be careful though because the `base()` method returns the element one after the orginal `reverse_iterator` had pointed to.  (This is so that reverse_iterators pointing at `rbegin()` and `rend()` work correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it is helpful, as this it the first hit on a search, here is a working example of using `rbegin`. This should be faster than using `std::stringstream` or `sprint`. I defiantly call a member `fmt_currency` many thousands of times in some print jobs. The `std::isalnum` is for handling a minus sign.

```
std::wstring fmt_long(long val) {//for now, no options? Just insert commas
    std::wstring str(std::to_wstring(val));
    std::size_t pos{ 0 };
    for (auto r = rbegin(str) + 1; r != str.rend() && std::isalnum(*r); ++r) {
        if (!(++pos % 3)) {
            r = std::make_reverse_iterator(str.insert(r.base(), L','));
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```