# Insert into vector in reverse order

Tags: c++, insert, iterator

Say I have two vectors (parents) of same size filled with some values. Out of these two vectors, I want to create two new vectors (children) of same size. For this, I cut the parents at a given position and fill the children after the following scheme:

```
Parent 1:
{1,  2,  3,  4,  5}
      ^cut
Parent 2:
{6,  7,  8,  9,  0}
          ^cut

Child 1:
{3,  4,  5,  0,  9}
Child 2:
{2,  1,  6,  7,  8}
```

In more **detail**, I cut parent 1 at position `k` and parent 2 at position `n-k`, where `n` is the size of parent 2.

Child 1 will then first be filled with the second part of parent 1. After that, the second part of parent 2 will be appended to child 1 in reverse order. Child 2 will initialy be filled with the first part of parent 1 in reverse order. After that, the first part of parent 2 will be appended to child 2 in forward order.

Now, inserting the parts in forward direction is not a problem. The backward insertion is what I can't get to work.

```
/* Set iterators at the cutting position */
int cut = 2;
auto cut1 = std::begin(parent1);
auto cut2 = std::end(parent2);
std::advance(cut1, cut);
std::advance(cut2, -cut);

/* Fill child1 with second part of parent1 */
child1.insert(child1.end(), cut1, std::end(parent1));
/* Add second part of parent2 in reverse order to child1 */
// ?
/* Fill child2 with first part of parent1 in reverse order */
// ?
/* Add first part of parent2 to child2 */
child2.insert(child2.end(), std::begin(parent2), cut2);
```

I was looking at `std::back_inserter` and `std::reverse_iterator`, but I'm not sure how they might work together and what is the most elegant way.

Also I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/300662/6608142) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13499478/6608142) question, which are not exactly the same but both seem to suggest, that I might have to work with simple for loops. Since both these questions are already a little dated, is there a nice way to achieve the required behavior with standard algorithms?

Comment: Why not insert in *un-reversed* (i.e. "normal") order, and then [reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) the vector afterwards?

Comment: Try `auto cut2 = std::rbegin(parent2);` with `std::advance(cut2, cut);` and `child2.insert(child2.end(), std::rbegin(parent2), cut2);`

Comment: I would first `resize()` both children to the sizes of the parents, then work with array indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reverse iterators to iterate through parents like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> parent1{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  std::vector<int> parent2{6, 7, 8, 9, 0};

  std::vector<int> child1;
  std::vector<int> child2;

  int cut = 2;
  {
    auto cut1 = std::begin(parent1); // set cut1 to element 1
    auto cut2 = parent2.rbegin(); // set cut2 to element 0 (reverse)
    std::advance(cut1, cut); // iterate cut1 to element 3
    std::advance(cut2, cut); // iterate cut2 to element 8 (reverse)

    child1.insert(child1.end(), cut1, std::end(parent1)); // copy elements 3, 4 ,5
    child1.insert(child1.end(), parent2.rbegin(), cut2); // copy elements 0, 9 (reverse)
  }
  {
    auto cut1 = parent1.rbegin(); // set cut1 to element 5 (reverse)
    auto cut2 = parent2.begin(); // set cut2 to element 6
    std::advance(cut1, parent1.size() - cut); // iterate cut1 to element 2 (reverse)
    std::advance(cut2, parent2.size() - cut); // iterate cut2 to element 9

    child2.insert(child2.end(), cut1, parent1.rend()); // copy elements 2, 1 (reverse)
    child2.insert(child2.end(), parent2.begin(), cut2); // copy elements 6, 7, 8
  }
  for (const auto& el : child1) {
    std::cout << el << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  for (const auto& el : child2) {
    std::cout << el << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Since C++14 you can use `std::rbegin(parent2)` instead of `parent2.rbegin()`.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. My error was to mix the `iterator` from `std::begin()` with a `backward_iterator`. That way `insert()` didn't work. Btw, I also found `std::reverse_copy(cut2, std::end(parent2), std::back_inserter(child1))` to work. Do you have an idea, which solution is more efficient?

Comment: I evaluated both solutions and your one is a bit faster.